# using CGContext to draw the shapes of the views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

How can I draw a triangle, say, shaped view with the help of `core-graphics` drawing techniques?

Comment: This is a slightly vague question, do you want help just drawing a triangle as an example? Where do you struggle in drawing?

Answer (score 0):

Implement `drawRect` on your view, and then just use the CGContextDraw-type methods to draw whatever you want.  It'll draw on the current context, which is your view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `drawRect` on your view. There are different drawing techniques. You can use bezier path and add it to your context or directly draw using `CGContext` methods. For example, triangle can be made using two methods `CGContextMoveToPoint` and `CGContextAddLineToPoint`.
For further understanding refer to docs of `CGContext`:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html